# FFplay audio output buffer / audio crackling

Tags: ffmpeg

When using FFplay, is it possible to configure the output buffer size?

For the first 60 seconds or so of playback, the audio tends to crackle like some buffer is underrunning.  It's not on the input side, as I can set `-infbuf` and FFplay will buffer gigs of audio/video ahead of the playback position.

Windows 10 x64, FFplay git-2019-10-23-ac0f5f4.

Comment: How can this issue be duplicated?

Comment: @llogan For me, it's as simple as `ffplay <video file>`.  That's it.  No other software has the audio crackling issue on my system.